# Writing a tuple and int key dictionary to file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tuples, pickle

I am trying to write a dictionary to (and read from) a file where the key is a combination of a tuple and an int as shown below:

```
Q = {((True, False, 1, 0), 1): 100}
```

I've tried pickle, json and csv but can't seem to get around the complex key problem, and I can't seem to find much documentation on this type of dictionary.

```
#json code which works for a tuple only as the key 

def write_file(mat):
    with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
         json.dump(mat, f)

def read_file():
    with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
        try:
            data = json.load(f)
        except ValueError:
            data = {}
    return data
```

Comment: can you post stacktrace (instead of trapping the error?)

Comment: `pickle` should be able to do it easily. What specific problem did you have with it—or do you have a preference for one of the others?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: It doesn't get that far—an unhandled exception occurs in `write_file()`: `TypeError: key ((True, False, 1, 0), 1) is not a string`

Answer (score 2):

This could potentially solve your issue. I basically convert the tuple that you have into a string, creating a new dictionary. I store this into the json file, and then use the `eval` built-in function to get the tuple back. While this works, be careful with the `eval` function if you don't know where your data is coming from.

```
Q = {((True, False, 1, 0), 1): 100}
Q_new = dict([(str(i),j) for i,j in Q.items()])

def write_file(mat):
    with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(mat, f)

def read_file():
    with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return dict([(eval(str(i)),j) for i,j in data.items()])

write_file(Q_new)
print(read_file())
```

Output:

```
{((True, False, 1, 0), 1): 100}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pickle works fine for me:

```
Q = {((True, False, 1, 0), 1): 100}

import pickle

with open("test", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(Q, file)
with open("test", "rb") as file:
    QQ=pickle.load(file)
print(QQ)
```

will output:

> {((True, False, 1, 0), 1): 100}

This is on python 2.7

Could you post your pickle code for comparison, including an error message ?

Comment: I'm not sure that "it works" is the proper way to answer. If it worked for the OP he/she wouldn't have posted here.

Comment: If OP would have posted the his/her pickle code, I would have corrected it. Regardless, I do think this is a good answer, OP wants a way to store this dictionary, possibly using pickle. My answer shows a way to do this. Even if OP would have posted code, in the end it would probably have lead to something like this.

Comment: Hey, I didn't post the pickle code considering the only difference from the JSON was 

pickle.dump instead of json.dump 

and I figured it just took up a lot of space in the question but my bad... 

So my code was identiccal to yours except with a try in the read file

and Yes I am using python 2.7 sorry should have included that in the question

Comment: No need to apologize. If I came over as aggressive I'm sorry. Could you try to run my code and post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, `pickle` can easily save and restore the contents of your dictionary with complex keys to a file (and read it back).

If you ***really*** want to use JSON format to do this, you can leverage off of that fact, and store the `pickle`d data as a value of a special key in a "normal" Python `dict`:

```
import json
import pickle

def my_dump(obj, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        pkl = {'_python_object': pickle.dumps(obj)}
        return _orig_dump(pkl, *args, **kwargs)
    return _orig_dump(obj, *args, **kwargs)

# monkey-patch json module to use our dump function (optional)
_orig_dump = json.dump
json.dump = my_dump

def as_python_object(dct):
    if '_python_object' in dct:
        return pickle.loads(str(dct['_python_object']))
    return dct

def write_file(mat):
    with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
         json.dump(mat, f)

def read_file():
    with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f, object_hook=as_python_object)
    return data

Q = {((True, False, 1, 0), 1): 100}
write_file(Q)
d = read_file()
print(d)  # -> {((True, False, 1, 0), 1): 100}
```